# How to use a Lable/Text Field from another Controller in javaFX

Tags: java, javafx-2

I'm trying to use a Label text from another controller.. Hear is my Code

> Design view

```
    <AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="cbc.MainController">
   <children>
      <BorderPane prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
         <top>
            <AnchorPane prefHeight="78.0" prefWidth="600.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
               <children>
                  <Label fx:id="lblName" layoutX="506.0" layoutY="32.0" text="Rifat" />
               </children>
            </AnchorPane>
         </top>
         <left>
            <AnchorPane prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
               <children>
                  <Button fx:id="btnHome" layoutX="49.0" layoutY="39.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#btnHome" text="Home" />
                  <Button fx:id="btnOne" layoutX="36.0" layoutY="87.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#btnOne" text="Seen One" />
                  <Button fx:id="btnTwo" layoutX="36.0" layoutY="136.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#btnTwo" text="Seen Two" />
               </children>
            </AnchorPane>
         </left>
         <center>
            <AnchorPane fx:id="acContent" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER" />
         </center>
      </BorderPane>
   </children>

    </AnchorPane>
```

Then i include another fxml file into `fx:id="acContent"` by this code

```
public class MainController implements Initializable {
@Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {

    try {
        acContent.getChildren().clear();
        acContent.getChildren().add(FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Home.fxml")));


    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(MainController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

on `Home.fxml` i insert a label and a button . 
if i click the button then label text will change as `fx:id="lblName"` which is a node from Main.fxml. and of-course Main.fxml and Home.fxml has different Controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can getController of `Home.fxml` this way:

```
FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader();
try {
    fxmlLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Home.fxml").openStream());
    MyControllerClass controller = fxmlLoader.getController();
    // Or use this to find your label
    Label myLabel = (Label) fxmlLoader.getNamespace().get("lblName");
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

**UPDATE:**

So here is more code to explain it a little bit better: Lets suppose you have your fxml file, some `MainViewController` controller and some `ListItemController` and ListItemController has fxml with Label you want to change. Here is what you can do: https://gist.github.com/varren/ac08d1855322c685adcf

`fxmlLoader.getNamespace().get("lblName");` will try to find view with id `lblName`specified in your xml

Comment: can't understand !  "Label myLabel = (Label) fxmlLoader.getNamespace().get("lblName");"
may you plz elaborate ?

Comment: i added more info  to the post, take a look at demo code on github

Comment: Thank you sir, 
i just fix it. but it needs a media class to passing data. 
i'm just add this line after your suggestion.  
`NameMedia nameMedia = new NameMedia();
        nameMedia.setName(lblName.getText());
        ListItemController controller = fxmlLoader.getController(); //controller defined in ListItem.fxml
        controller.setMedia(nameMedia);`